# Excel: retrieve data based on a column

Tags: excel

I have an excel document with a checklist like this one:

```
| number | yes/no | notes           |

|  1     |  yes   | blablabla       |
|  2     |  yes   | twinkle twinkle |
|  3     |  no    | little star     |
```

I'd like to "echo" the fields which are set as "no" (in the second column) in another sheet, echoing the columns "number" and "notes". The result of my example would be:

```
| number | notes           |

|  3     | little star     |
```

How could I do it? Thanks!

Comment: Filter on "no" then copy and paste the values then delete the second column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your Main Table is in Sheet2, range A2:A4 (row 1 being headers).  Use this formula, as an array (enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>) in your sheet 2:

`=INDEX(Sheet2!A$2:A$4,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$4="No",ROW(Sheet2!A$2:A$4)-ROW(Sheet2!A$2)+1),ROWS(Sheet2!A$2:A2)))`

This will return all the `Numbers`.  To get the `Notes`, change the very first index range to `Sheet2!C$2:C$4`.  Obviously adjust your range down as necessary (I doubt you only have 4 of these).

Finally, just wrap an `IfError()` around that, so it looks nice when you use it.  As you add data to your table, your table of only "no" values will update.

`=IfError(INDEX(Sheet2!A$2:A$4,SMALL(IF(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$4="No",ROW(Sheet2!A$2:A$4)-ROW(Sheet2!A$2)+1),ROWS(Sheet2!A$2:A2))),"")`.

edit:

Screenshots:
[image]

[image]

(Using the `IfError([above formula],"")` wrapper hides the `#NUM` results when there's no match.)

Comment: Something goes wrong, it prints always the max value instead of the exact one! For example, if I have 15 points and the 2 and 3 are set to "No", I get two times 15! What could it be?

Comment: @MicheleStieven - Hmm, perhaps you're accidentally entering the formula incorrectly?  I've updated my post with a screenshot. I've put my "output" table on the same page, you can do the same, then just move it when you get it working.

Comment: The only difference I see is that I'm using Excel 2007, I think the difference are that it doesn't surround the function with {} and it uses ; instead of , in functions! Here's my image, I wrote the translations because I have the italian version:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/cujtg0utvr6o90r/example.png?dl=0

Comment: @MicheleStieven - Ah! You'll notice I used `Row()` and `Row*s*()`. The very last one should be `Rows` (in Italian), not `Row()`. that should help hopefully!

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't notice it, and always used `Rows` in italian, because the translation of `Row` is a bit tricky. Damn excel functions!! Thank you again, you've been super speedy!

Comment: @MicheleStieven - Glad to hear it worked! Do you mind marking as answer (click the check outline left of my post)?